# Current directory after was moved by another user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, filesystems

I have a terminal which is opened on a folder a:

```
hostname:/path/to> mkdir a
hostname:/path/to> cd a
hostname:/path/to/a> cat > b.txt
```

Another user has moved the folder to another location

```
hostname:/path/to> mv a /another/hidden/path/i/dont/know
```

I would like to know where he moved it.

The old terminal still works, but pwd shows the old path because the way that the linux file system works. Old absolute path not exists of course:

```
hostname:/path/to/a> ls
b.txt
hostname:/path/to/a> pwd
/path/to/a
hostname:/path/to/a> ls /path/to/a
ls: cannot access /path/to/a: No such file or directory
```

I thought about traversing the upper hierarchy and look for the correct folder in each level:

```
hostname:/path/to/a> ls ../
...
hostname:/path/to/a> ls ../../
...
hostname:/path/to/a> ls ../../../
...
```

However this solution may be very hard if one of the levels contain a lot of subdirectories. In my specific case it is not possible as I don't have permissions in one of the upper levels.

I guess it may be impossible to find the exact path, because of the way that linux fs works (e.g. there may be a lot of hard-links for the same directory). I don't care to get some candidates for the path, is there a way to find an absolute path which enables me to approach the directory?

Comment: `find / -d -name "a"` ? Or based on `Another user has moved the folder to another location` maybe check their history ?

Comment: I don't know who is the user (actually it was an IT user). Furthermore if I had a very non special directory name (e.g. a...) it will not work. In addition he may rename directory (in the above example, he renamed it to "know" if there was no "know" directory before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: I may use lsof on a uniquely-named subfolder (I should traverse into it so it is considered as "opened"):

```
hostname:/path/to/a> mkdir uniquely_named_directory
hostname:/path/to/a> cd uniquely_named_directory
hostname:/path/to/a/uniquely_named_directory> lsof | grep uniquely_named_directory
```

It can be done only if I have such folder or have write permissions to the folder. Alternatively, if I know that the folder was not renamed and has a name which is special enough, I may simply try "lsof | grep a".

(Based on idea suggested here in a deleted answer...).

Comment: To cd into it you'd have to know where the top folder was though. This answer makes no sense.

Comment: It worked for me... anyhow as I said I already have an opened terminal on the directory but the shell thinks it is the old path.

Comment: You never moved the dir in this example.

Comment: Look at "hostname:/path/to> mv a /another/hidden/path/i/dont/know"

Comment: I know that, but you `cd` into "uniquely_named_directory" with `cd uniquely_named_directory`. If you do this you should end up in the old path. Eg you are in `/path/to/a/uniquely_named_directory` and not `/another/hidden/path/i/dont/know`

Comment: You are correct that the path appears in the shell is still "a/uniquely_named_directory". But the path shown in lsof is the correct one - to "/another/hidden/path/i/dont/know/uniquely_named_directory". The reason is because that's the way that linux filesystem works. I published this solution because it worked for me, I suggest that if it doesn't work for you just try it and upload your output so we can compare.

Comment: Im not at home so i can't try, I just thought it sounded odd. It's interesting if it works. It does however require you to already be in that directory before it's moved, but i guess that that was what you asked for. Good solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `find / -d -name "a" -exec cd {} \;` to change to the moved directory, assuming that the user didn't change it's name. If you would like to get the path to the moved directory use `find / -d -name "a" -exec echo "path is {}" \;`

**EDIT**

If there are more directories with the same name and you know when the dir was moved, use `find / -d -name "a" -mmin -$minutes -exec echo "path is {}" \;`  where `$minutes` is the time it was changed at to find all dirs name "a" changed in the specified time period.

If someone renamed and moved the diretory, you need to do some manual work. Use `find / -d -mmin -$minutes -ls` to list all dirs changed within the specified time period.

As hellerpop says, you might want to use `-cmin` instead of `-mmin`

Comment: I think mv only effects the ctime not mtime so you should rather use -cmin.

Comment: plus 1 for the idea, but this is not my case.